# stacked Bar charts in Bokeh

Tags: python, bar-chart, data-visualization, bokeh

I am drawing bar charts with Bokeh( http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide.html ). It is an amazing tool but at the same time I think it is a little bit immature currently. I have a stacked bar chart with 30 categories on x axis and 40 classes corresponding to each category. I am not able to find out the function that can enable me to change colors (colors right now are very ambiguous) and align legend to top. Alternatively, if a information box can be opened when someone hovers over that color, that can be helpful. I have a very little clue if that can be done.

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/charts.html#bar

My example is similar to this one except that I have many variables.

Any suggestions?
UPDATE:
I tried myself the below solution but it looks like there is some problem with Bar(). It does not recognize Bar().

```
import bokeh.plotting as bp
data24 =OrderedDict()
for i in range(10):
    data24[i] = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
figut = bp.figure(tools="reset, hover") 
s1 = figut.Bar(data24, stacked= True,color=colors )
s1.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"x":"$index"}
```

Running it I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'Bar'
```

Here are the bar colors that I am getting. There is no way to distinguish between colors.
[image]

Comment: bokeh.plotting.figure returns a PlotObject. ```Bar``` is not a member of PlotObject, which explains your exception. The ```Bar``` you are looking for can be imported with ```from bokeh.charts import Bar```.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a dig in the [bokeh source code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh) and it seems that the `bokeh.charts.Bar` method will except some keyword arguments. These can be properties of the `Builder` class which includes the `palette` property, defined [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/3134cdd802c6969274c8227b3231f27b4d383e1e/bokeh/charts/_builder.py#L80). You should be able to pass this as an argument therefore to `Bar`.

```
Bar(...,palette=['red','green','blue'],...)
```

Just tested this out by modifying the [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/3134cdd802c6969274c8227b3231f27b4d383e1e/examples/charts/file/stacked_bar.py) that bokeh provides:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show 
from bokeh.sampledata.olympics2014 import data

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['data'])

# filter by countries with at least one medal and sort 
df = df[df['medals.total'] > 0] 
df = df.sort("medals.total", ascending=False)

# get the countries and we group the data by medal type 
countries = df.abbr.values.tolist() 
gold = df['medals.gold'].astype(float).values
silver = df['medals.silver'].astype(float).values
bronze = df['medals.bronze'].astype(float).values

# build a dict containing the grouped data 
medals = OrderedDict(bronze=bronze, silver=silver, gold=gold)

output_file("stacked_bar.html")

bar = Bar(
    medals, countries, title="Stacked bars", stacked=True, 
    palette=['brown', 'silver', 'gold'])

show(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the original question and other answer are very out of date. The `bokeh.charts` API was deprecated and removed years ago. For stacked bar charts in modern bokeh, see the section on [Handling Categorical Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#stacked)

Here is a complete example:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("stacked.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar_stack(years, x='fruits', width=0.9, color=colors, source=data,
             legend=[value(x) for x in years])

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

[image]